# SQL Syntax AND OR clause issues

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am querying a DB using the following:

```
SELECT * FROM DB.table WHERE 
hidden = 0 AND
column1 LIKE '%$search%' OR
column2 LIKE '%$search%';
```

However even if the hidden column is 1 it still outputs the query.

This is likely so simple but I think I have looked at it too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put parentheses around the `OR`'d conditions.

The precedence by default is this way:

```
    (hidden = 0 AND column1 LIKE '%$search%')
OR  (column2 LIKE '%$search%')
```

You want it to behave this way:

```
    (hidden = 0)
AND (column1 LIKE '%$search%' OR column2 LIKE '%$search%')
```

If you've ever studied boolean algebra or logic you might recall that *logical AND* has parallels to regular multiplication while *logical OR* has a correspondence to addition. So if you think about the order of operations from junior high algebra class it's a good way to remember this. And you'll probably get into the habit of checking for this anytime you see `OR` in a query.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem!

Answer (score 3):

```
    SELECT * FROM DB.table WHERE 
    hidden = 0 AND   
    (column1 LIKE '%$search%' OR 
    column2 LIKE '%$search%');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query is being parsed as:

```
SELECT *
FROM DB.table
WHERE (hidden = 0 AND
       column1 LIKE '%$search%'
      ) OR
      column2 LIKE '%$search%';
```

because of the precedence rules for `AND`/`OR`.  There are several ways to fix this:

```
SELECT *
FROM DB.table
WHERE hidden = 0 AND
      (column1 LIKE '%$search%' OR column2 LIKE '%$search%');
```

Sometimes, it is convenient to concatenate the fields for the `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM DB.table
WHERE hidden = 0 AND
      CONCAT(column1, ' ', column2) LIKE '%$search%'
```

(This isn't exactly the same.)

If you are doing searches of this sort, you probably should learn about `match`.  Full text indexes are often the best solution for this type of query, particularly if you care about performance.